# Numbers of rows to process

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, for-in-loop

I would like to make sure that an e-mail is not send twice. The script itself is working, however the Insertion of:

`sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);`

does not work, yet it adds a random value to row 40.

Could someone help me figure out the problem? Thanks a lot already in advance!

```html
function sendEmails() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2);  
   var subject = range.getValues();   
   var range = sheet.getRange(1, 9);  
   var numRows = range.getValues();   
   var startRow = 4;                  
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows,9) 
   var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
   var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
   for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[0];      
      var message = row[8]; 
      var emailSent = row[5]; 
      if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,{noReply: true});
          sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I suspect `startRow + i` is evaluating to combining the text string 4 with the text string of i, which is probably "0", giving you "40"  Perhaps try forcing these to numbers: `parseInt(startRow) + parseInt(i)`

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Instead of using `for(i in data){...}` use `for(var i = 0;i < data.lenght;i++) {...}`

## Explanation

`for (variable in object)` assigns a different property name on each iteration but what you need is the data index to be used to calculate the row index.

## Reference

- [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)