# Google Script Email with CC

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, for-in-loop

I'm having an issue where I want to be able to send an email with CC's based off cell values. i.e. both the main recipient email and CC email are in the spreadsheet in the same row. The code should cycle through each row and send an email to the recipient and attaches the CC to that email.

My code is as follows:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // Start at second row because the first row contains the data labels
  var numRows = 10; // Put in here the number of rows you want to process

  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B4
  // Column A = Email Address, Column B = First Name
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:C")

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
   var row = data[i];
    var name = row[0];
   var emailAddress = row[1]; 
   var daysAbsent = row[2];
   var CC = row[3];
   var message = "Hi " + name + ",\n. We see that you have been absent for " + daysAbsent + " days."; 
   var subject = "Attendance Notification";
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,{
         cc: CC
         });
  }
}
```

Comment: what's not working?

Comment: Related [Numbers of rows to process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44522392/1595451)